# Dialogflow custom authentication

Tags: ios, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

I have an iOS app that connects to dialogflow agent.  The dialogflow agent uses google cloud functions to fulfill the users request.

In the iOS app I’m using Firebase authentication to authenticate the user.  I would like to include the Firebase idtoken in the dialogflow request so that I can access the idtoken In the cloud function. Is this possible? If so how could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem i have decided to create my own server for fulfilment rather than using fulfilment in dialogflows. All dialogflow requests are now sent to the server and then the server calls dialogflow. If an intent requires fulfilment a custom payload is added to the response in dialogflow.